# Linq in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I have a json string as below

```
{
    'Sheet1': [{
        'EmployeeNo': '123456',
        'EmployeeName': 'Midhun Mathew'
    }, {
        'EmployeeNo': '123457',
        'EmployeeName': 'Bill Gates'
    }, {
        'EmployeeNo': '123456',
        'Address': 'AAAA'
    }, {
        'EmployeeNo': '123457',
        'Address': 'BBBB'
    }]
}
JObject parsedJson = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

// Get the EmployeeNo's 

List<JToken> tokenList = parsedJson["Sheet1"]
                           .GroupBy(d => d["EmployeeNo"])
                           .Select(s => s.Key)
                           .ToList();

// Get the tokens which have the Same 'EmployeeNo'

foreach (JToken j in tokenList)
{
    IEnumerable<JToken> t = parsedJson["Sheet1"].Where(s => s["EmployeeNo"] == j);
}
```

But in the foreach I am getting only the first one which is

```
{
  "EmployeeNo": "123456",
  "EmployeeName": "Midhun Mathew"
}
```

I am not getting what I am doing wrong here.

My original intent is to group the JTokens having same EmployeeNo into one JObject

So in the above case I will get 2 JObjects since there are 2 different EmployeeNo's

Hope I am clear

Comment: Replacing your forloop code with firstordeafult worked for me..var t = parsedJson["Sheet1"].FirstOrDefault(s => s["EmployeeNo"] == j);

Comment: `var tokenList = parsed["Sheet1"]
                .OrderBy(o => o["EmployeeNo"])
                .SelectMany(grp => grp.Skip(1));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do here, but you seem to be grouping by `EmployeeNo`, then throwing away the results to get just the keys, and then trying to do the grouping again in a more manual way.

If you remove the `Select(s => s.Key)` part, then you could just use the groupings directly:

```
var tokensByEmployeeNo = parsedJson["Sheet1"].GroupBy(x => x["EmployeeNo"]);

foreach (var grouping in tokensByEmployeeNo)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {grouping.Key}");

    foreach (var token in grouping)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(token);
    }            
}
```

If you want to create a 'new' `JObject` for each of these groupings, then you probably want to create a `JArray` per group:

```
var groupedArrays = parsedJson["Sheet1"]
    .GroupBy(x => x["EmployeeNo"])
    .Select(groupedRecords => new JArray(groupedRecords));
```

The first of these would look like this, for example:

```
[
  {
    "EmployeeNo": "123456",
    "EmployeeName": "Midhun Mathew"
  },
  {
    "EmployeeNo": "123456",
    "Address": "AAAA"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Your understanding is right.. But i want it as a JToken rather than a var so that i can add the values in the var into seperate jObjects. Is that possible here?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean.  `grouping` in this case implements `IEnumerable<JToken>` - that's the same return type you had in your question.  The `token` variable in the inner loop is of type `JToken`.

Comment: I tried changing to `IEnumerable<JToken> jt = (IEnumerable<JToken>)parsedJson["Sheet1"].GroupBy(x => x["EmployeeNo"]);`  But I am getting exception which says : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`3[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken,Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken,Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken]'. Really sorry for these dumb questions. I am new to this.. thats why.

Comment: That won't work.  Look at how I've used it.  It's a collection of groups, so `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<JToken>>`.  That's why I've used two loops.

Comment: @MidhunMathew I've updated my answer to show how you'd create a `JArray` for each group.

Comment: @MidhunMathew Good to hear.  It did just occur that this possibly isn't what you're after, I thought you may have wanted a `JObject` with 3 properties (EENo, Name and Address).

Comment: I think my question was also unclear. will take care of tht next time

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to go through the list of Employees, here's how I am used doing:

```
   var json = @"
                        {
                'Sheet1': [{
                    'EmployeeNo': '123456',
                    'EmployeeName': 'Midhun Mathew'
                }, {
                    'EmployeeNo': '123457',
                    'EmployeeName': 'Bill Gates'
                }, {
                    'EmployeeNo': '123456',
                    'Address': 'AAAA'
                }, {
                    'EmployeeNo': '123457',
                    'Address': 'BBBB'
                }]
            }";

            var array = JArray.Parse(JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("Sheet1").ToString());

            foreach (var arrayElement in array)
            {
                var employeeNo = JObject.Parse(arrayElement.ToString()).SelectToken("EmployeeNo");
                var employeeName = JObject.Parse(arrayElement.ToString()).SelectToken("EmployeeName");

                Console.WriteLine("Number: {0}, Name: {1}", employeeNo, employeeName);
            }
```

Output:

[image]